# What are the first 6 characters in a line of a COBOL program used for?

Tags: cobol

I am looking at a COBOL program that has the following line:

```
T41037*         SELECT  XX
```

This is part of a SQL statement. I believe the `*` indicates that it is commented out. But what does the T41037 mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Originally the first 6 characters held the line number, this was quite important in the punch card days (try dropping a bunch of cards on the ground and then putting them back in the correct sequence with out line numbers).

These days it can be anything. Some sites use it for change numbers or some other special use. Try asking the people you work with, there is no generic Cobol meaning

Comment: Same goes for anything after column 72.

Comment: Both correct.  Cols 1-6 and 73-80 are ignored... At least in mainframe COBOL.

Comment: You *can* still have sequence numbers and have the compiler check them, with Enterprise Cobol. See compiler options NUMBER and SQUENCE. SEQ can be useful for "spotting" something in column six which should be in column seven, like "*".

Answer (score 0):

Also, the "T" in column 1 might indicate that this line is to be compiled and run when you are in test mode.  I've seen that in some places but I think it was more like a "T" in column 7 instead of an "*".

All systems are different and different shops run different test software.